# How to use a Dbset of EF Core to retrieve data from a specific table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have two DbSets `Info` and `Num5Info` based on the same model info to retrieve data from two tables.

[the two DbSets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxVTX.jpg)

`DbSetInfo` is for table `dbo.Info`, dbSet `Num5Info` for table `dbo.Num5Info`.

First I use `DbSetInfo` to retrieve data from table `dbo.Info`, and it works:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index( string name)
{
    if (null == name)
    {
        return _context.Info != null ?
                      View(await _context.Info.ToListAsync()) :
                         Problem("Entity set 'MvcCarContext.Info'  is null.");
    }

    var info = _context.Info!.Where(i => i.Name!.Equals(name));

    return View(await info!.ToListAsync());
}
```

[the url and the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn2e4.jpg)

Then I change the code to use DbSet `Num5Info` to retrieve data from table `dbo.Num5Info` - but it failed:

[the tabke dbo.Num5Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBCTJ.jpg)

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index( string name)
{
    if (null == name)
    {
        return _context.Num5Info != null ?
                      View(await _context.Num5Info.ToListAsync()) :
                         Problem("Entity set 'MvcCarContext.Info'  is null.");
    }

    var info = _context.Num5Info!.Where(i => i.Name!.Equals(name));

    return View(await info!.ToListAsync());
}
```

[the same url and response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tXqO.jpg)

Comment: are the tables related ? what do you mean by same Model ? please provide further info

Comment: hello everyone . if there's anything that confuse you. welcome to comment to let me known. thank you in advance.

Comment: the table dbo.Info is created by scaffolded item related to Dbset<> Info.  another table dbo.num5Info is created manually by sqlscript.

Comment: so they are not related ?

Comment: both DbSet<Info> Info and DbSet<Info> Num5Info have the same entity Info(a class under the folder models).

Comment: yes, i learn it from the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio.  however. i need to create many tables so i try this way to see if it could work. so i don't know how to make the DbSet and table related.

Comment: Info and Num5Info are just two different names for the same DBSet. If the tables are exactly the same, there is really no reason to have two of them. Otherwise, you will have to create a class Num5Info so that your Num5Info table can map to that class.

Comment: thank you very much. i also think that there's no need to create so many tables. but my manager said that every car should have two tables(one holds the information and another holds the task the car has taken )even the tables have exactly the same structure . so i choose this way to give it a try